# How can I use loop concept in below code (code is use for python robot frame work)

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, selenium2library

How can I use loop instead of repeating using  keywords.
 code is for selenium python robot framework 
 could you please suggest how i can use and help to provide some more solution by using loop

```
Click Link    //body//section[@id='home-acuvue-block']//div//div//div[1]//a[2]
Click Link    //a[@href="https://acuvuevision.jp/contact"]
Click Link    //div[@class='content-col']//a[@class='ext']
Select Window    locator=NEW
Scroll Element Into View    //div[@class='acuvue']//tr[2]//th[1]
Set Selenium Speed    5s
Select From List By Value    xpath=//select[@id='ctl00_CphForm_FormListCategory']    1
Select From List By Value    xpath=//td[@class='input']//select[@class='ctSelecthasCustomSelect']  21
Scroll Element Into View    //body/div/div/div/form[@name='aspnetForm']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/th[1]
Set Selenium Speed   5s
Input Text    name=ctl00$CphForm$UcInquiry$FormDescription    product is not good
Input Text    name=ctl00$CphForm$UcUser$FormUserFirstName    xxxx
Input Text    name=ctl00$CphForm$UcUser$FormUserLastName   xxxxxxxx
Input Text    name=ctl00$CphForm$UcUser$FormUserFirstNameKana    xxxxxxx
Input Text    name=ctl00$CphForm$UcUser$FormUserLastNameKana    xxxxxxxx
Input Text    name=ctl00$CphForm$UcUser$FormMailAddress   zzzzzzz@gmail.com
Input Text    name=ctl00$CphForm$UcUser$FormMailAddressConf    zzzzzzz@gmail.com
Input Text    name=ctl00$CphForm$UcTel$FormTel1    12
Input Text    name=ctl00$CphForm$UcTel$FormTel2    5463
Input Text    name=ctl00$CphForm$UcTel$FormTel3    4356
Select From List By Value    xpath=//select[@name='ctl00$CphForm$UcTel$FormListAppM']    3
Select From List By Value    xpath=//select[@name='ctl00$CphForm$UcTel$FormListAppD']    5
Select From List By Value    xpath=//select[@name='ctl00$CphForm$UcTel$FormListAppT']    1
Click Button    //input[@name='ctl00$CphForm$btnSubmit']
Click Link    //a[@href="javascript:window.close();"]
```

Comment: Great (but old) article: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/05/robot-framework-tutorial-loops-conditional-execution-and-more/

Comment: And this is a new way how to do for loops: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#templates-with-for-loops